# Heredoc syntax error

Tags: php, mediawiki

For a mediawiki skin, I am getting an error for the following piece of code

```
    private $_sideboxf = <<<EOD
        <h3>%s</h3>
        <ul class="submenu">
            %s
        </ul>
EOD;
```

The error is `syntax error, unexpected T_START_HEREDOC` . I have checked the syntax and I dont know what is wrong. Even the author of the code doesn't understand why I am getting this error when I asked on git.

EDIT: class definition

```
class SkinTemplate extends QuickTemplate
{
    private $_sideboxf = <<<EOD
    <h3>%s</h3>
    <ul class="submenu">
        %s
    </ul>
EOD;
// Some public function
} // End of Class
```

Comment: [Heredocs apparently don't work in classes.](http://codepad.org/O4zy120L) Just use single quotes, I suppose.

Comment: What do you have preceding this statement?

Comment: @minitech: I've had to use this necessary evil for a google maps upgrade. Putting the JS code within a class is nasty, but it does provide the benefits of OOP in that the JS is now in a centralized location.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP5.3.0+ is required for initializing class-variables using heredoc, your code works fine in PHP 5.3

Comment: Mediawiki 1.17.0 has PHP version 5.2.9

Comment: This has got the be the issue, the code in OP looked like it would compile. Been on 5.3.x so long, hard to think others are not.

Comment: I just called my shared hosting provider and they asked me to purchase a VPS account for $40/mo, as they had no upgrade planned until a proven stable version estblished itself. I guess I'm moving.

Comment: Wow, current stable is 5.3.8 not 5.2.9 . PHP 5.3.0 was released in 2009 ^^

Answer (score 4):

You really want to do that heredoc during member variable initialization? Maybe a better route to take would be something like:

```
class MyClass 
{
    public function getSideBoxF()
    {
        return <<<EOD
            Stuff goes here...
EOD;

    }
}
```

Also note that the closing HEREDOC must be flush against the left margin, I added the class wrapper to show you what it should look like.

Answer (score 1):

Is the end tag of the heredoc actually indented?

That doesn't work out well IIRC...